# My Ubuntu's default icons and theme were partially 'reset'?

Tags: themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I restore the original color scheme, icons, and theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194899/how-do-i-restore-the-original-color-scheme-icons-and-theme)

For some reason, my icons and part of my theme seemed have 'reset' to default?

[image]

I don't remember doing anything. Just started using Ubuntu 2d.

Any suggestions to fix this problem?

(I'm using Ubuntu 11.10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st try reset your unity by using this command

```
unity --reset
```

Rebuilt icon package

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Unity-icon-theme'
```

Other default icon package

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Ubuntu-mono-dark' 

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Ubuntu-mono-light'
```