# How do I restore the original color scheme, icons, and theme?

Tags: appearance

I'd like the original colour scheme, icon style of 12.04.

I somehow lost the Ambiance theme (possible error or upgrade error).
I re-installed 'light-themes' from the terminal and got it back.

But the panel on the top that shows the options of sound, battery and wi-fi has changed and I *can-not get the original setting back.*

In the windows, the close, minimize tools have shifted to the right instead of the original left side.

I had installed MyUnity and Ubuntu Tweak but deleted them. As such, I want the original setting back.

Kindly help me with the commands.

I have searched for solutions; there are multiple and I need to be sure if I should follow the same. Kindly bear before marking duplicate.

Discoveries:

- The appearance is gray and boxy [as outlined here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42889/upgraded-to-11-04-and-now-most-of-the-ui-is-gray-and-boxy). Not sure same problem.
- Similar 'gray and boxy' [article here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/fix-ubuntu-linux-mint-theme-changing-to.html).
- Desktop [forgets theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme).
- I have also tried the `unity --reset` command. It never completes. I gave it 20 minutes.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

**Reset Icon Pack**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme ''
```

**Reset Theme**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ''

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme ''

gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/theme ''
```

**Reset Launcher**

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

**Reset Panel**

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

After run this command logout and login back.

Comment: Worked perfectly. 
Thank you @penreturn for your assistance. 
This makes Ubuntu look good again. There are other threads on similar lines, shall go there and redirect them here. It may help them.

Comment: Great! Enjoy Ubuntu Sir!

Comment: +1 Nice answer. I deleted mine as it was completely wrong. [D'oh!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27oh!)

Comment: This just made my terminal completely black and I was unable to read anything  then all the text turn black

Comment: This did not work for me, but replacing all the `''` with the theme name did. For example, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Ambiance'`

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command from a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

```
unity --reset-icons
```

This will reset the Unity icon cache.

Answer (score 0):

When trying [penreturns's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/194922/80278), I encountered UI unresponsiveness at some steps. So, it may actually be better to copy and paste the commands and run them as a one-liner.

> Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme ''; \
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ''; \
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme ''; \
gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/theme ''; \
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites; \
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['all']"
```

> After run this command logout and login back.

However, I did see the following errors:

```
Command 'gconftool-2' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gconf2
No such schema “com.canonical.Unity.Launcher”
No such schema “com.canonical.Unity.Panel”
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is reinstall MyUnity and open up the themes menu. There is a button to reset it to the defaults, but you can manually set the theme to "Ambiance" and the icon theme to "Ubuntu-Mono-Dark" and that should bring you back to the default 12.04 set-up.