# title bar display glitch with ambiance and radiance window theme on background window

Tags: gnome, themes, ambiance

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with gnome-shell and default Ambiance window theme. There is a display glitch on title bar of background windows. It can be seen on the screenshot below.

The bug also occurs with with Radiance window theme, and also when I use gnome-classic.

I must have messed with some configuration file on my home directory because this problem doesn't occur with another account (guest account in fact).

What can I do to simply get rid of this annoying display glitch ?

[image: Display glitch on background window]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194899/how-do-i-restore-the-original-color-scheme-icons-and-theme/194922#194922) ?. What is your gnome version?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The instructions provided by your link did not change anything. I use version 3.4.1 of gnome-shell.