# Desktop theme is damaged after changing Ubuntu theme

Tags: icons, themes, icon-themes

I changed my Ubuntu theme a few days ago and it worked perfectly. It is Mediterranean or something like that, a gtk theme. Then I wanted to change my cursor theme , and that worked as well ( although it did make quite a mess in the files from the icons folder). I also put on an icon theme and it worked, but now when I restarted my PC several days after it's a combination of ambiance and my theme. The apps look like my theme, and nautilus looks like ambiance. The icon pack has been removed completely as well. Only my mouse works now.

I tried logging out and back on, and also restarting. What can I do to repair my Ubuntu theme?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I configure Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the original color scheme, icons, and theme?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194899/how-do-i-restore-the-original-color-scheme-icons-and-theme)

Comment: @Zanna I advise retracting your close vote because the answer to this question worked and is useful, and it isn't duplicated in any of the answers to either of the two linked duplicate questions.

Comment: @karel done, the question is a lot clearer after your edit but I couldn't verify the answer so trusting your judgement there

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution ! If anybody else is having a problem and a reboot won't solve it , i ran: `unity`
In the terminal. That's the reset command that worked for me.. if not try :`unity-reset`.
And for nautilus to show the theme again : `killall nautilus`.

Hope it helps anybody having this problem.