# Restoring default Ubuntu theme/icon set

Tags: themes, icons, icon-themes

Funny story, I installed the Ubuntu Kylin theme as discussed [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/whats-name-icon-theme-screenshot-answered) and when I decided I didn't like the "Ubuntu Kylin" theme (mostly because I didn't like the new boot screen & greeter), I removed it...

But now the icons are buggered-up.

[image: Incorrect icon set]

Here's what I did to remove the Ubuntu Kylin theme, and also to try to fix the issue (using information I found on Ask Ubuntu)...

```
sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntukylin-theme

sudo apt-get autoremove --purge  light-themes

sudo apt-get install  light-themes

sudo apt-get install  ubuntu-desktop

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Following all this, I restarted the computer, which clearly did not fix the issue.

Obviously it's a theming issue, but what package do I need to re-install and/or how do I actually re-apply the default Ubuntu 16.04 theme?

Comment: Have you tried this answer? http://askubuntu.com/a/194922/308164

Comment: Use `Unity-Tweak-Tool` to reset the icons. It's even mentioned in the original link you posted.  Alternatively, there's `gsettings` way , which is also mentioned by luchonacho's link

Comment: The gsettings method didn't work, but resetting the appearance settings in Unity Tweak did... I was sure I had already tried to reset the appearance settings in Unity Tweak, but apparently not.

Thanks!

Comment: May we close your question as duplicate then ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the original color scheme, icons, and theme?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194899/how-do-i-restore-the-original-color-scheme-icons-and-theme)